# MEAN app is not working because of System.config.js missing in angular 4

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack

i am new to MEAN stack app, i have tried the sample by using angular 2 (having system.config.js) and index.html file having link to this file but when i tried same simple example with angular 4(doesn't have system.config.js) and index also not having any link to any JS file.

So I am stuck in the step where we giving the static folder setup in the NodeJs server file

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var login = require('./routes/login');

var port = 3000;

var app = express();

//View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));****/**/ i  guess the erro is here need help to fix this.******



// Body Parser MW
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', login);

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Server started on port '+port);
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DfmApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>

  <app-root>Loading</app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

[this is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE8MN.png)

Comment: Have you seen this: https://auth0.com/blog/real-world-angular-series-part-1/

Comment: I changed the static folder setup            using below line even though it  is not working                                                        app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './dist'))); i can't find the dist folder path

Comment: can anyone help me.  i can't find the examples with angular-cli.json file and express js static folder setup